# MySQL Query not excluding fields

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a query which updates special product prices in a website, It's working fine, however some of the products won't update their prices because the SKU fields are very similar to each other, example:

**Product 1 sku: 255**

**Product 2 sku: 255rab**

Here are my tables:

```
TABLE product_special

product_id is the FK here

product_special_id | product_id | customer_group_id | price | priority
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12322              | 15468      | 1                 | 5,49  |    1
42223              | 15468      | 2                 | 3,60  |    1
23332              | 15468      | 6                 | 2,34  |    1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

TABLE product

product_id is PK here

product_id | sku                 | price | manufacturer_id
----------------------------------------------------------
 15468     | 255                 | 5,49  |    35
 15468     | 500                 | 3,60  |    36
 15468     | 5377                | 2,34  |    14
```

My code:

```
 foreach ($priceList as $sku => $price) {
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE product_special 
 INNER JOIN product ON product.product_id = product_special.product_id
 SET product_special.price = :price, customer_group_id = 1, priority = 1
 WHERE sku = :sku;');
 $stmt->bindParam(':price',  $price);
 $stmt->bindParam(':sku', $sku);

 if ($stmt->execute()){
 $message = "<span style=\"color: #c4000b;\">Client prices successfully updated.</span>";
 } else { 
 print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); 
 }
  }
```

**List of things I tried before coming for help:**

```
'WHERE sku = :sku AND product.sku NOT LIKE \'%eglo%\' OR \'%rab%\';'

'WHERE sku = :sku AND product.manufacturer_id NOT IN(35,36);'

'WHERE sku = :sku AND product.manufactuer_id NOT LIKE(SELECT manufacturer_id 
 FROM product WHERE manufacturer.id IN (35,36)';
```

**EDIT**

As people commented where the priority column comes from, it's from product_special. It's an OpenCart platform and without setting priority to 1, the special product won't generate itself in the product_special table.

**SECOND EDIT**

SHOW CREATE TABLE of my tables:

PRODUCT:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
 `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
 `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
 `isbn` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
 `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
 `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `points` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date_available` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
 `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
 KEY `model` (`model`),
 KEY `sku` (`sku`),
 KEY `upc` (`upc`),
 KEY `manufacturer_id` (`manufacturer_id`),
 KEY `sort_order` (`sort_order`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `date_available` (`date_available`),
 KEY `date_modified` (`date_modified`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=21002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

PRODUCT_SPECIAL:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_special` (
 `product_special_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `customer_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `priority` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
 `date_start` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 `date_end` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`product_special_id`),
 KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=37585 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Another thing I noticed is that the products which won't update their prices are not present in the product_special table, perhaps the SET priority = 1, customer_group_id = 1 is not working for them.

Comment: from where `priority` came?

Comment: You're not only updating the price, but also two other fields. That could mean you would update all three rows in `product_special`, were it not that `priority` is not an existing column. I don't think you have the problem you think you have, or your question is missing a lot of information.

Comment: *"some of the products won't update their prices because the SKU fields are very similar"* - are you *sure* that's the cause? It seems unlikely from what you've shown here - unless you're storing the SKU in an `INT` (type) field, so it's stripped the *rab* ending. I'd go back and look at the db - data types and FK restrictions in particular - if I were you.

Comment: @ÐℛẲḰỮℒѦ product_special table, I just edited the question.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I just edited the question, priority comes from product_special table and it's required.

Comment: @CD001 I just checked the db structure and the sku column is a VARCHAR type, all other products that have unique sku update their prices, only those with similar won't update.

Comment: I assume those aren't *real* product ids? Being as they're all the same value...

Comment: @CD001 They are just an example, however most of the products are just like that - with 3 special prices for 3 different customer groups.

Comment: Odd - I've created some tables that match your structure, put an FK (cascade) restriction in place and lobbed in some data - one product with an SKU of `255` and another `255rab` ... and it all works as expected... it's got to be something else, surely?